# How do I Submit data from a vuejs form to zapier webhook using axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, webhooks, zapier

I am using vuejs / axios and I want to post data to a zapier webhook.

I've tried a number of things. However I continually get the following error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/7349379/owviy9/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is my code:

```
submit(){       
  axios
    .post(
      'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/7349379/owviy9j/',
      this.formData,
     {headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}}
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I've also tried this but can't seem to get it to work:

```
var data = this.formData
axios.create({ transformRequest: [(data, _headers) => JSON.stringify(data)] })
 .post('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/7349379/owviy9j/', data) 
}
```

How do I resolve this CORS issue?

Comment: You are probably running your app locally, and it's actually your browser that is blocking you from doing the request. You could serve your app through a small web-server (node, and express) And make your axios post request to your own server and from there forward your request to zapier. Don't know if this makes any sense to you, but that's the most long lasting solution that I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

From your first example just remove:

```
{headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}}
```

Zapier dosn`t allow headers to be sent.

Complete example:

```
const res = await this.$axios.post('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxx/xxx/',
    JSON.stringify(data)
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

When you try to make requests from the same machine but with different ports. Example: Your front end is running on port 3000, while your nodejs app is running on port: 8080. For security concerns the browser doesn't let you make the api requests.

Solution: Add Cors to your NodeJs App.

1. `npm install cors`
2. `const cors = require('cors')`

`const app = express();`

3. just add a line below this: `app.use(cors());` //use it as a middleware and this will resolve your issue.